# Angular 12 how to return an http get request array of objects and assign to other array of different type using map()

Tags: javascript, angular, http, rxjs, request

Hey I'm trying to implement a bootstrap5 dropdown following this example: [Creating Multi-Select Dropdown with Angular and Bootstrap 5](https://codeomelet.com/posts/creating-multi-select-dropdown-with-angular-and-bootstrap-5)
In that example, to get the data, he uses an app.service and just returns an array of objects:

```js
getFoods(): Food[] {
        return [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Grapes'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Melon'
            },
...
```

And then in his ngOnInit() calls the getFoods() method and also uses .map() operator because he has to assign to values because the item model has two values:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.items = this.appService.getFoods().map(fruit => ({
            id: fruit.id,
            name: fruit.name
        } as Item));
    }
```

So I'm trying to do hat but with data being fetched from an API endpoint using HTTP GET request.
But I don't know how to use the .map() operator for the http get request:

```js
this.subscription = this.contactSearchService.currentCodes.pipe(
            map(
                code => (
                    {
                        id: code.code,
                        name: code.code
                    }
                )
            )).subscribe(Response => {
                this.items = Response
            })
```

It's giving me these errors:

```
Property 'code' does not exist on type 'ResponsibilityCode[]'.
Type '{ id: any; name: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Item[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
```

My http get request function:

```js
private _reponsibilityCodeSource = new BehaviorSubject<ResponsibilityCode[]>([]);
currentCodes = this._reponsibilityCodeSource.asObservable();

getCodes(): void {
    this.http.get<ResponsibilityCode[]>('https://localhost:44316/api/SITEContacts/ResponsibilityCode').subscribe(Response => {
        this._reponsibilityCodeSource.next(Response);
      });
  }

I get the data as `JSON` btw.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rxjs `pipe(map(.... code...))` is different than array.map -
`pipe(map())` does not operate on each item of an array

So the errors you are getting is because you're swapping out the array of ResponsibilityCode for a single item (`code` in your code is all the responsibility codes)

Try

```
this.subscription = this.contactSearchService.currentCodes.subscribe(Response => {
                this.items = Response.map(
                code => (
                    {
                        id: code.code,
                        name: code.code
                    }
                )
            )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTP get returns an `Observable` of `ResponsibilityCode` array, so to achieve that you have to `map` ([Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) the items of the array within the RxJS's [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) operator, like the following:

```js
this.subscription = this.contactSearchService.currentCodes
  .pipe(
    map((res: ResponsibilityCode[]) =>
      res.map((item) => ({
        id: item.id,
        name: item.name,
      }))
    )
  )
  .subscribe((res) => {
    this.items = res;
  });
```